# Is there a way to add up items(numbers) in the listbox and display them in the same box in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

So I'm a beginner in vb class and am wondering how I can add up all products of Modnumber(variable name) Mod 2 so that i can attach them into one single line at the bottom of my listbox. What line should i add so the program runs like the pic below?

```
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim Modnumber As String

    number = InputBox("I'm kindly asking you to tell me a number", "Number")

    LstNumber.Items.Clear()

    Do Until number = 1
        Modnumber = number
        LstNumber.Items.Add(number & vbTab & Modnumber Mod 2)
        'each time it devides the number by two until number = 1
        number \= 2

    Loop
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8arY.png)

[This is what I'm supposed to get in my lstbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbfek.png)

Comment: `While number > 0 LstNumber.Items.Add(number & vbTab & (number Mod 2))     number \= 2 End While`. Make a comparison (running both, line by line, with a Debugger - put a Breakpoint in `LstNumber.Items.Clear()` and follow step-by-step).

Answer (score 0):

```vb
'capture your original input to use in the final result
Dim input = InputBox("I'm kindly asking you to tell me a number", "Number")

Dim number As Integer = input
Dim modNumber As Integer 'Changed this to a number
Dim result As New StringBuilder 'Used to store the product of doing Mod 2

LstNumber.Items.Clear()

Do Until number = 0 'loop until 0 instead of 1
    modNumber = number Mod 2 'Do mod outside of LstNumber add so u can retain the value
    LstNumber.Items.Add(number & vbTab & modNumber)

    result.Insert(0, modNumber) 'Build your result string
    number \= 2
Loop

'Add your additional stuff
LstNumber.Items.Add("Therefore")
LstNumber.Items.Add($"{input} = {result.ToString}") 'Original input plus built string
```